# Stripe - When using the `stripe.paymentMethods.create` where does it save it?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a paymentMethod using stripe. but right now I am wondering if I won't associate the created paymentMethod from the `stripe.paymentMethods.create` to a costumer where will it go?

Can I still view it from the dashboard? is there a way to delete the paymentMethod alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes nowhere, but you probably won't be able to find it after the fact.

If you create a PaymentMethod and you don't attach it to a customer or use it in a charge, the ID will still exist and you'll still be able to use it but you won't be able to find it later if you didn't save the ID.

If you charge a PaymentMethod but don't save it to a customer, it gets "consumed" and won't be able to be used for anything else even if you did save the ID locally.

You can't delete PaymentMethods, just detach them from customers. Which in effect achieves the same result as you won't be able to retrieve them if you don't save the ID elsewhere.

Comment: Is it safe to get PaymentMethods from customers that way?

Comment: Sure, you can't do anything with PaymentMethods without a secret key.

Comment: Thank you very much! You've been a great help! :)